# sed/regex - Updating source files with scope issues

Tags: c++, c, regex, linux, sed

I have a project originally written for Windows, and I am currently in the process of porting it over to Linux. Most of the platform specific code has been `#ifdef`'ed or wrapped, so it's been easy so far.

This project has about 2000 instances of `gettext()` scattered throughout about 200 source files (`.cpp` and `.c` compiled as C++). The intended function call is:

```
std::string boost::locale::gettext(const char*);
```

This works in Windows, but in Linux builds, it resolves to:

```
char * gettext (const char * msgid);
```

Which I assume it's resolving from `<libintl.h>`, which is interesting, since I'm not including it.

What I need to do is to do the following:

---

1. Find in all my source files (ignoring the `.svn` directories):

   1.1. Lines containing `gettext(.*).c_str()` and modify them to become `boost::locale::gettext(.*).c_str()`.

   1.2. Lines containing `gettext(.*)` and modify them to become `boost::locale::gettext(.*).c_str()`.

---

What's the best way to accomplish this, preferably using BASh and sed, or some command-line-fu in general? The requirements for `1.1` I could probably do easily enough, but `1.2` is a bit more complex, and I'm not sure how to have it know which right parentheses `)` to append `.c_str()` to correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed this is not doable with a regex in the general case, since you cannot define a matching parenthesis. Wouldn't it be easier to define an inline function or macro?

Comment: @Ctx The problem is that right now, I think there are some cases where a macro is being used, and other places where it isn't. The cleanest solution IMHO is just to explicitly specify the namespace/scope and be done with it, but was hoping there's a way to automate this.

Comment: Maybe just go over it with a regex which matches 99% (i.e. assume that no parenthesis are nested in the call to gettext) and fix the rest by hand.

Comment: @Ctx If you have a regex handy that would accomplish that, I would accept that as an answer. It might not be "perfect", but if it gets the job done with caveats/limitations known in advance, it's fine by me. :)

Comment: (untested) `sed -r "s/gettext\(([^()]*)\)(\.c_str\(\))?/boost::locale::gettext(\1).c_str()/g"` should leave invocations with nested calls untouched and replace the rest.

Comment: @Ctx Thank you. This did the trick. I was able to then create an SVN diff file, make just a handful of manual changes to it, and then re-applied the patch to a clean local working copy. Saved me a ton of time. If you post this as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is not solvable with a regex in the general case, since you cannot find the matching closing parenthesis of the `gettext()`-call with it if other calls are nested in its argument list.

But if usually no nested calls are made, it might be an option to just fix these cases automatically and do the rest by hand.

This sed expression

```
 sed -r "s/gettext\(([^()]*)\)(\.c_str\(\))?/boost::locale::gettext(\1).c_str()/g"
```

should leave invocations with nested calls untouched and replace the rest.